# Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.IInAppBillingService... on a null object reference

Tags: android, class, null, in-app-billing

Hi everyone i have an issue with Billing, when I click on the button i call in a another class this method:

```
public void launchPurchase() {
    BillingManager.getInstance().setActivity(this);
    BillingManager.getInstance().Initialize();
    BillingManager.getInstance().tryToPurchase("pubgame");
}
```

I obtain the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.Bundle com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService.getBuyIntent(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at inappbilling.BillingManager.tryToPurchase(BillingManager.java:57)
at com.kingerino.erwan.colorun.succes.launchPurchase(succes.java:377)
at com.kingerino.erwan.colorun.succes$2.onClick(succes.java:157)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5205)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21164)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:745)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:171)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5456)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

This is my claas BillingManager

```
public class BillingManager extends Activity{
IInAppBillingService mService;
private static BillingManager ourInstance = new BillingManager();

public static BillingManager getInstance() {
    return ourInstance;
}


private BillingManager() {
}
public void Initialize() {
    // Payment etc
    ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mService = null;
        }
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
            // Do something here
        }
    };

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
    serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
    activity.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}


/** A/D
 *
 */

public void tryToPurchase(String idProduct) {
    Bundle buyIntentBundle = null;
    try {
        buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, activity.getPackageName(), idProduct, "inapp", "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
        if (pendingIntent == null) {
            return;
        }
        activity.startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/** Getter/Setter
 *
 */
public void setActivity(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

/** A/D
 *
 */
private Activity activity;


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1001) {
        int responseCode = data.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", 0);
        String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
        String dataSignature = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                String sku = jo.optString("productId");
                String packageName = jo.optString("packageName");
                String purchaseToken = jo.optString("purchaseToken");

                if (sku.equalsIgnoreCase("pubgame")) {
                    // Do something here...
                    //int response = BillingManager.getInstance().getmService().consumePurchase(3, packageName, purchaseToken);
                }/*
                else if (sku.equalsIgnoreCase("myItem2")) {
                    // Do something here...
                    //int response = BillingManager.getInstance().getmService().consumePurchase(3, packageName, purchaseToken);
                }*/
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
public void getPurchaseStatus(String idProduct) {
    try {
        Bundle ownedItems = null;
        ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, activity.getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
        int response = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
        if (response == 0) {
            ArrayList<String> ownedSkus = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");

            for (int i = 0; i < ownedSkus.size(); ++i) {
                String sku = ownedSkus.get(i);
                if (sku.equalsIgnoreCase(idProduct)) {
                    // Do something here...
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


}
```

I use the code on github : https://gist.github.com/adrienfenech/a477de4d16b118402faf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initialization of billing service is asynchronous. Therefore, immediately after calling BillingManager.getInstance().Initialize(); the variable mService is null and you get the exception.

It becomes initialized after mServiceConn.onServiceConnected() is called.

You can make it correctly by one of the following ways:

1. Initialize in-app billing service at the app startup, and check mService for null after calling tryToPurchase()
2. Implement a listener of mServiceConn.onServiceConnected(), and run tryToPurchase() after the billing service has been initialized.